# another method to find digital root of a number

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I was solving a recursion problems and then i came across a problem finding the digital root a number which is nothing but sum of the digits until we get a single digit number
example
173= 1+7+3=11 =1+1=2

but then i observe a thing that this can be calculated as
173 = 17+3 =20=2+0=2

it was mere a observation while thinking to avoid maintaining a separate variable to store sum of digits

can somebody explain the logic behind second method as am beginner these things are greek to me and am unable to find a logical explanation

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better match for math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: This is less of a programming problem, and more of a mathematical problem. You could post on [the math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com) to ask for help with a proof of your observation.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is try a few more numbers to see if the second approach consistently works and I'm not looking at coincidence.

Comment: You'll also have to formalize the rules of what you are proposing. It's not clear from your example what would happen with 4 digits. 1234 -> 12+34? or 123 +4?

Comment: `17+3` is not a sum of the digits of the number, so it is not valid.

Comment: While the math site is the site for this question, if I recall well, the sum of digits can be done using "sub-numbers", just because this thing is `mod 9` related.

Comment: @user4581301 i tried on 4 digits too let's take your example 1234 
123+4=127;
12+7=19;
1+9=10;
1+0=1;
which is same as 1+2+3+4= 10=1+0=1.
thanks for advising i will ask this question on math se site

Answer (score 1):

This is not so hard to understand when you realize that 173, 137, 731, 713, 317, and 371 all have digits that sum to the same result (2). This is just the associative property of addition. In fact, you can choose ANY groupings of the digits and arrive at the same result. If we define a function f(x) as the digital root of x, then

```
  f(173) = f( f(1) + f(7) + f(3) ) = f( f(17) + f(3) ) = f( f(31) + f (7) ) = etc.
```

Because ultimately you are just adding all of the single digits together recursively, the associative property lets you deal with the digits in any order that you want.

RESPONSE to Ripi2 comment:

Let x, y, z be the digits of a 3-digit number:

```
f(xyz) = f(x + y + z) = f(x) + f(y) + f(z)
f(xy + z) = f(10*x + y + z) = f(x0 + y +z) = f(x + y+ z)
```

Because multiplication by 10 appends zeros to any digit, you can add subunits of the original set, in any order, without changing the result.

RESPONSE to Jarod42 comment:

f(x+y) = f(f(x) + f(y)) is not a property of f. It is the definition of the "digital root" algorithm.

Comment: What the OP points out is the fact of summnig values before summing digits. 2543->25+43 (=68) ->6+8=14->5

Comment: But we have to prove property of `f`: `f(x+y)==f(f(x)+f(y))` and so on...